# nvidia-smi не видит всех GPU

Tags: cuda, nvidia

После обновления cuda c 11.2 до 11.5 перестали отображаться GPU

[image: nvidia-smi видно только одно GPU хотя физически есть tesla k80]

[image: sudo ubuntu-drivers devices]

При попытке установить любой драйвер из списка указанного на скриншоте получаю ошибку:
[image: Пробую установить драйвер из списка. Рекомендованные на скрине дают такую же ошибку]

[image: torch.cuda.device_count()]

Если захожу на этот же комп под windows видеокарты тесла к80 видны.

Подскажите как вылечить эту проблему.

Comment: Проверяйте GPU на совместимость с CUDA [Compute Capability](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

Comment: Зашел по ссылке получил следующее:Tesla Workstation Products
GPU Compute Capability
Tesla K80 3.7
Tesla K40 3.5
Tesla K20 3.5
Tesla C2075 2.0
Tesla C2050/C2070 2.0

Comment: А какая версия CUDA на венде?

Comment: Я кажется разобрался в проблеме. Для К80 cuda 11.4 драйвер есть , для 11.5 еще нет. Попробую понизить версию cuda до 11.4

Comment: Более правильно было бы сказать - "уже нет". NVIDIA толсто намекает, что старушкам пора на пенсию (а вам - в скобяную лавку за новым железом)

Answer (score 0):

Понижение версии CUDA с 11.5 до 11.4 и установка драйвера 470 решило проблему. Все GPU обнаруживаются в nvidia-smi